# List not iterating properly inside android WebView

Tags: kotlin, android-webview

I have a list of Urls and I want to iterate over the list to load each one of them, but when trying to do that, the iteration fails, and it only loads the last item of the list.

Initially, this url is being loaded when the WebView first starts running:

```
webView.loadUrl("https://translate.google.com/?sl=$from&tl=$into&text=Hello&op=translate")
```

I have a list of Urls that I want to iterate over them:

```
 val items = listOf(
        "https://translate.google.com/?sl=$from&tl=$into&text=First text&op=translate",
        "https://translate.google.com/?sl=$from&tl=$into&text=Second text&op=translate",
        "https://translate.google.com/?sl=$from&tl=$into&text=Third text&op=translate"
    )
```

When the page finished loading, I iterate over the list to load each one of the urls:

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                GlobalScope.launch {
                    delay(5000)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        items.forEach {
                            view?.loadUrl(it)
                            injectJavascript(view)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I get only the result of the last Url, which is "Third text", what's the problem? And how can I make the code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to the fact that WebView's `loadUrl()` function operates asynchronously.
When you call `loadUrl()` in your `forEach` loop, it initiates the loading of the URL, but it does not wait for the page to finish loading before proceeding to the next URL.
Consequently, the loop quickly iterates over all the URLs and only the last URL has the chance to fully load, which is why you are only seeing the result of the last URL.

To handle this, you could use a queue-like approach, where you load the next URL only when the current one has finished loading.

For instance:

```kotlin
val items = mutableListOf(
    "https://translate.google.com/?sl=$from&tl=$into&text=First text&op=translate",
    "https://translate.google.com/?sl=$from&tl=$into&text=Second text&op=translate",
    "https://translate.google.com/?sl=$from&tl=$into&text=Third text&op=translate"
)

var isLoading = false

webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        isLoading = true
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        isLoading = false
    }
}

val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
val runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        if (!isLoading && items.isNotEmpty()) {
            val nextUrl = items.removeAt(0)
            webView.loadUrl(nextUrl)
            injectJavascript(webView)
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
    }
}
handler.post(runnable)
```

In this revised code:

Here, `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` are used to maintain a flag `isLoading` that indicates whether the WebView is currently loading a page or not.
The `runnable` object checks this flag, and if the WebView is not currently loading a page, it starts loading the next URL. This `runnable` object is posted to a `Handler` every 5 seconds.

In this way, the next URL is loaded only when the WebView is not currently loading a page.

---

> Ok, it's working, but why are the URLs loading twice?
> Not in a row necessarily, but after several other requests are made, the same request is made after that.

The `WebViewClient` `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` methods are called multiple times per single `loadUrl` call due to the nature of how web pages load - they load multiple resources like scripts, stylesheets, images, frames, etc. Therefore, if a web page has `iframes`, for example, these methods can be called for each iframe's URL.

One way to ensure that you only react to the main page load is to compare the URL parameter in the `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` callbacks with the URL you are loading. If they match, then it is the main page load. Here is how you can modify your code to do this:

```kotlin
val items = mutableListOf(
    "https://translate.google.com/?sl=$from&tl=$into&text=First text&op=translate",
    "https://translate.google.com/?sl=$from&tl=$into&text=Second text&op=translate",
    "https://translate.google.com/?sl=$from&tl=$into&text=Third text&op=translate"
)

var isLoading = false
var currentUrl: String? = null

webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        if (url == currentUrl) {
            isLoading = true
        }
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        if (url == currentUrl) {
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
}

val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
val runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        if (!isLoading && items.isNotEmpty()) {
            currentUrl = items.removeAt(0)
            webView.loadUrl(currentUrl!!)
            injectJavascript(webView)
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
    }
}
handler.post(runnable)
```

Here, a `currentUrl` variable is introduced: each time a new URL is loaded, `currentUrl` is updated to that URL.
Then, in `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished`, the `isLoading` flag is updated only when the `url` parameter matches `currentUrl`. This ensures that `isLoading` reflects whether the main page is loading, not any of the subresources.

Comment: This didn't help, the code above doesn't allow the initial url to load, it loads "First text" then jumps to "Third text"

Comment: @Roony OK, I have updated the code to address this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes only the first Url to load!

Comment: @Roony OK, let's try with a `isLoading` flag. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Ok it's working, but why are the urls loading twice? Not in a row necessarily, but after several other requests are made, the same request is made after that.

Comment: @Roony Good point. I have edited the answer to address your comment.